# Calling a same servlet from different windows(or sessions)

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet to display selected items. Whenever i call this servlet, it should be opened in a new window only if it is from different sessions. can anyone help me out in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The servlet itself produces only HTML (or some other output). It cannot decide where it will be displayed (new window, new tab, and so on).

If you want to open a page in a new window, you have to do that on the link or JavaScript that opens the page.

Comment: I hav two browsers. each for two different users to shop. and i hava a servlet called "cartcontent". When i cal ths servlet, only one window is opened. Rather than opening two seperate windows..

Can u help me in ths?

Comment: How do you call the servlet? If you want to open it in two browsers, you will have to open it twice (once for each browser).